# Retrieving Records between Two different dates in Android

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, date, datetime

I am working in my Android application.

I have stored records witch also stores date in the format : **yyyy-mm-dd**

Everything is ok with that format i.e. Retrieving records between specific dates but, When i was storing date in **02-09-2015(dd-mm-yyyy)** format, I could not get specific records.

So,I just want to know that, We must have to keep the format of the date as **yyyy-mm-dd** to get the task done or Is it possible to retrieve records between specific dates while doing same with the format **02-09-2015(dd-mm-yyyy)** ?

If Yes, Please, tell me How ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use function `STR_TO_DATE`

`select STR_TO_DATE('05.02.2012','%d.%m.%Y')` will give you '2012-02-05'

`select STR_TO_DATE('05-02-2012','%d-%m-%Y')` will give you the same result, but supposes that `-`s are used. After this do everything you want with the date output value

Comment: OK thanks, What we have to prefer as a datatype for date, VARCHAR or DATETIME ?

Comment: @Jaimin. That depends upon your tables' structure. You did not provide any information on this. Anyway it seems to be another question, doesn't it?